# lua attempt to call field 'createUDPSocket' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I am writing a LUA script, when I run the program, this result as below:

```
socket = net.createUDPSocket()
```

*attempt to call field 'createUDPSocket' (a nil value)*

I have been searching for many website, there seems to no much details about that. Could anyone help?

Comment: Post your code if you still need help with this.

Answer (score 1):

That simply means that the `createUDPSocket` function does not exist. Without seeing your code, that is the most anyone here is going to be able to help you with.